# GAE PHP app.yaml login redirect to preserve URL

Tags: php, google-app-engine, authentication, app.yaml

I have a app.yaml file setting as below

```
- url: /page.php
  script: lex/page.php
  login: required
```

Now I have a DNS redirect setup such that website.com/page.php  loads  app.appspot.com/page.php

```
ProxyPass /page.php http://app.appspot.com/page.php
ProxyPassReverse /page.php http://app.appspot.com/page.php
```

What happens is that when I open website.com/page.php in a browser it does the login and all but finally loads  http://app.appspot.com/page.php   instead of opening http://website.com/page.com

I tested with an testpage.php that does not need login and it works fine. Any idea how to preserver the URL name?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to serve off a custom domain, you should use the custom domain support:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain

Comment: I tired that but I got an error.You do not have the permissions necessary to install this application. It might be cause app.appspot.com is set up to have domain logins from domain1.com  while I am trying to add   website.com/page.php is on domain2.com  These are all google domains.